# cakePHP 3 and Bootstrap-ui Declaration of App\View\AppView::initialize()

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I have installed the Bootstrap-UI plugin with composer and loaded the plugin in the bootstrap.php.

When I add the necessary code to the ViewApp.php I get an error.

```
Strict (2048): Declaration of App\View\AppView::initialize() should be compatible with Cake\View\View::initialize() [APP/View/AppView.php, line 22]
Code Context
*/
class AppView extends View
{
```

The code I added is:

```
class AppView extends View
{

    public $layout = 'BootstrapUI.default';

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->loadHelper('Html', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Html']);
        $this->loadHelper('Form', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Form']);
        $this->loadHelper('Flash', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Flash']);
        $this->loadHelper('Paginator', ['className' => 'BootstrapUI.Paginator']);
     }
```

Comment: What's unclear about the error message? **https://www.google.com/search?q=cakephp+strict+declaration+should+be+compatible&hl=en**

Comment: I am using a clean version of CakePHP and the bootstrap-ui plugin so I would not have expected this error. I am not comfortable altering the plugin code to get around this. I was wondering was there another step that is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: The error isn't in the plugin, it's in your code, that's what the error message is saying, it's your app views `intialize()` method signature declaration that doesn't match its overwritten parent.

Comment: sorry I am being a bit stupid. I only have the plugin and a clean install of cakephp. I have no other code. The only code that I copied was the code the plugin wanted into the ViewApp.php

Comment: In case the plugin instructions come with that code example, then that's something that should be fixed in its docs, however, the problem is still not in the plugin code itself, it's in your app code, so you can safely change it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I deleted the 'array $config' in the initialize function.

```
public function initialize()
{
   // Code from Plugin
}
```

You also need to add `<?php $this->extend('../Layout/TwitterBootstrap/dashboard'); ?>` to your views to get the bootstrap look.